# Prolog operation when creating a fact

Tags: prolog

I know if I have the fact

```
temperature(2 + 2).
```

And then ask

```
-? temperature(X)
```

The answer will be X = 2 + 2

How would I write the fact, retaining the 2 + 2 operation, so that it would be evaluated as temperature(4) instead of temperature(2 + 2)

Comment: What do you mean, *before the creation of the fact*? What exists before the fact is created?

Comment: Your update isn't much clearer. What do you mean by, *retaining the 2+2 operation*? There's no way to have a fact `temperature(2+2).` and have `temperature(X)` directly return `X = 4`. You need to have an evaluation done with, for example, `is/2`. What you're trying to achieve here (the context) is unclear.